# Semantic-release does not auto-release the already pre-tagged versions to github-releases

Tags: node.js, npm, github-actions, cicd, semantic-release

### Issue

Semantic-release does not auto-release the already pre-tagged versions to github-releases. This means it does not work for the versions, which were already tagged before setting up semantic-release on the repo.

My sample GitHub repo with proper config files: https://github.com/gouravkhator/temp-git/tree/7ff47c8deb5c5093ded1fde16b555b0b06d1aab0

### Expected behavior

As said in [this official docs](https://semantic-release.gitbook.io/semantic-release/usage/configuration#existing-version-tags), the semantic-release should work on existing tags of a particular repo.

### Other details

- semantic-release version: ^19.0.5
- CI environment: Github Actions

Comment: Note: I have also opened a git issue for this at https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release/issues/2552

Comment: So what's the question? If you filed a bug with the maintainer I don't really see a question here.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @fredrik I have updated the question. If you can help me with this issue, it will be much helpful.
I have added the issue to get some help from the maintainer, but have not heard from them yet.

Comment: I don't see it saying that previous tags will be published automatically.

Comment: @fredrik Is there any other way to auto-release previous tags? Or should I do some bash scripting for previous tags??

Comment: You'll have to write a script to do it.